# configuring SSH on a Linux virtual box appliance

Tags: ssh, systemd, virtualbox

I have setup a bitnami LAMP appliance (7.3) on my ubuntu laptop. It starts fine. I need to get Putty working with it so I can load my application.

For networking I am trying to use bridged adapter for adapter 1. 
I am using wireless on my network.

My understanding is that there are issues with wireless when using bridged adapter. I have tried to enable the SSH with these commands:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

After this I check the status with sudo `systemctl status ssh` but I get

```
Loaded: loaded
Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed. 
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run
```

I am wondering if I should move away from the bridge config and instead use NAT for the network and use Host only for adapter 2 instead? How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a file `/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run`?  You appear to have a start condition that checks if that particular file does not exist, and if it does, `sshd` will not start.

Comment: Christopher your answer got me over the hump. Thank you!

Comment: Christopher, I don't know what "the close" is. Is there some document that I need to read?